# How to arrange objects like in 'snake' in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the idea is how to align objects like in photo below, what formula need to use for this?
[image]

Now I can only do it this way, through sin or cos

[image]

```
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        characters.Add(Instantiate(characterPrefab, charactersParent));
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.Count; i++)
    {
        float x = Mathf.Cos(i * verticalLines * Mathf.PI / characters.Count) * horizontalRadius;
        characters[i].GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector3(x, -i * (1920f / characters.Count), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to move it like snake, or move arround every angle but add balls like snake?

Comment: @Lotan I want 'move arround every angle but add balls like snake'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In snake your rewards/bug eated are added on the opposite direction that the last body-part is facing.

[image]

The problem here is how you stablish your current snake movement, to get the opposite direction.

Let's guess that your movement is `x += 1`, then your opposite position will be your X position on your `characters[characters.Count]` and go on the opposite direction `x -=1`.